# How to calculate exponential moving average using ClickHouse inbuilt function exponentialMovingAverage?

Tags: clickhouse

```
┌─offset─┬───  RecvHour       ─┬─   IpAddr    ─┬─── AVG(column)         ┬────exponentailMovingAverageEMA(5, column)   ─┬
│      0 │ 2023-03-02 23:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [137.6612992781788]    │                                              │
│      1 │ 2023-03-02 22:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [127.08613804905876]   │                                              │
│      2 │ 2023-03-02 21:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [170.75601821730643]   │                                              │
│      3 │ 2023-03-02 20:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [145.4665304036791]    │                                              │
│      4 │ 2023-03-02 19:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [157.1682892906815]    │                                              │
│      5 │ 2023-03-02 18:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [133.7664298401421]    │                                              │
│      6 │ 2023-03-02 17:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [116.70383451059536]   │                                              │
│      7 │ 2023-03-02 16:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [141.6947754353804]    │                                              │
│      8 │ 2023-03-02 15:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [161.09584450402144]   │                                              │
│      9 │ 2023-03-02 14:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [122.21212121212122]   │                                              │
│     10 │ 2023-03-02 13:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [124.50695825049702]   │                                              │
│     11 │ 2023-03-02 12:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [129.23307086614173]   │                                              │
│     12 │ 2023-03-02 11:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [128.10786739238]      │                                              │
│     13 │ 2023-03-02 10:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [112.29431721798134]   │                                              │
│     14 │ 2023-03-02 09:00:00 │ 172.30.56.214 │ [129.2812363952982]    │                                              │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┴
```

I am trying to calculate EMA using Clickhouse inbuilt function which accepts half-life decay, column and timestamp. I have a SQL query which returns above dataset. Can anyone please explain how EMA function in clickhouse works?  I have tried like  exponentialMovingAverage(half-life decay)(`AVG(column)`, RecvHour)) OVER (PARTITION BY IpAddr ORDER BY RecvHour ASC Rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS EMA(column).

half-life decay calculated using the formula t1/2 = (ln 2) / λ
where t1/2 is the half-life, ln 2 is the natural logarithm of 2 (approximately 0.693), and λ is the decay constant. The decay constant is a characteristic of the substance undergoing decay and is related to the probability of decay per unit time.
λ  which is 2/(N+1) where is N is windows size for which EMA is requested.

Please don't check syntax here. I have just given an example. I am trying to understand how its works in clickhouse. How can we partition the data set to get EMA?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`intDiv(toUInt32(time),3600))` -- need to adjust DateTime to timeunits (`/ 3600`), otherwise it will be 3599 zeros + 1 non-zero.

Probably you can use `offset` as timeunit.

```sql
CREATE TABLE slava_ukraini
ENGINE = Memory AS
SELECT
    10 AS value,
    toDateTime('2020-01-01') + (3600 * number) AS time
FROM numbers_mt(10);


SELECT
    value,
    time,
    exponentialMovingAverage(1)(value, intDiv(toUInt32(time),3600)) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC) res
FROM slava_ukraini
ORDER BY time;

┌─value─┬────────────────time─┬─────────res─┐
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 │           5 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 01:00:00 │         7.5 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 02:00:00 │        8.75 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 03:00:00 │       9.375 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 04:00:00 │      9.6875 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 05:00:00 │     9.84375 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 06:00:00 │    9.921875 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 07:00:00 │   9.9609375 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 08:00:00 │  9.98046875 │
│    10 │ 2020-01-01 09:00:00 │ 9.990234375 │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

`intDiv(toUInt32(time),3600))` -- need to adjust DateTime to timeunits (`/ 3600`)

Comment: Could you please explain why you have used 1 here exponentialMovingAverage(1)?

Comment: What? Why do you think so? I just showed an example. Read documentation https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/exponentialmovingaverage/#exponentialmovingaverage